# How to exclude a singular, specific machine from a domain-wide PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, scripting

At my current location, we run a couple of PowerShell scripts daily to reboot all computers. Recently, a relatively critical system from another office on base has started having issues directly after said reboots, and remains in this state until technicians go out to remedy the issue, which is generally not until 4-5 hours later, which isn't acceptable; it's regarding BitLocker Recovery Passwords, but that's not entirely relevant to the question. While I've contacted the affected users and informed them that they can run "shutdown -a" in PowerShell to stop the reboot from occurring, themselves, my coworkers and I would like to implement a solution into our reboot script to simply skip this particular machine until that issue is remedied or the system is rebuilt.

I've tried looking online in many different locations, including here, and I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem, which I why I ask my own question. I'm also not very knowledgeable on PowerShell scripting.

Here's the code:

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format "ddMMMyyyy"
$computers = Get-Content “[Source File Location]\Output Files\ADComps$Date.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    IF (test-connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet){
        Write-Host "$Computer is connected"
        shutdown /r /t 1800 /c "Please save your work. This computer will reboot in 30 minutes." /m \\$computer
        }
    Else{
        Write-Host "$Computer not connected"
        $Computer | Out-File “[Output File Location]\Output Files\RebootComps_NoConnection$Date.txt" -Append
        }
}
```

If having another file/program/command injected into the code from our network drive is the best way to achieve this, that would be fine as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple Powershell coding. I strongly suggest you learn PS rather than tinker with scripts you don't understand in a live environment. You should test this before deploying it.

The following assumes that your text list is simply a list of short computer names

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format "ddMMMyyyy"
$computers = Get-Content "[Source File Location]\Output Files\ADComps$Date.txt"
$ComputerToSkip = 'problemcomputername'

ForEach ($computer in $computers) {
    If ($computer -eq $ComputerToSkip) {
        Write-Host "Skipping $ComputerToSkip"
    }
    Else {
        If (test-connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet){
            Write-Host "$Computer is connected"
            shutdown /r /t 1800 /c "Please save your work. This computer will reboot in 30 minutes." /m \\$computer
        }
        Else{
            Write-Host "$Computer not connected"
            $Computer | Out-File “[Output File Location]\Output Files\RebootComps_NoConnection$Date.txt" -Append
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with arguments, but would avoid additional if's and use `Where-Object` to exclude the one when reading in the computers.

Comment: Well, obviously I don't needlessly mess with things, and only modify things I know how to modify or that are very clear to do. This wasn't, to me, hence the question lol

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: LotPing, I used the conditional to make it easier and more informational for the OP in this context.